# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2382

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am trying to connect SSAS engine(SQL Server Denali) but its failing with following error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2382"
SSAS service is running under Network Service account and SQL Browser service are running on Local system acc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What OS are you running?
I had a similar problem and resolved the issue changing the sql server browser account from  a built in account to a name account with password.

**Open sql server configuration management**

1. Right click sql server browser and select properties.
2. In the Log On Tab select "This account:" radio button. You can enter a user and password or you can press the browser button. I use my admin log for the local machine where SQL server is installed.
3. If press the browser button when the select user or group page appear press the Advance button and select one of the account.

In BID you may need also to impersonate your Data Source. It is a dirty solution but work for me in a vista machine where I installed SQL Server R2 for practicing. Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: In my case it was running as Local Service and I had to change it to Local System account (by checking the radio button), and it worked! :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you SQL Browser is running under the wrong account. If you run that under network service account does it work. As always with issues like this check the basics such as network connectivity and firewall settings just in case this error is misleading.